# Копия MoveClip в коде

Tags: flash

Подскажите, как создать копию MoveClip в коде, не ссылку, а чисто другой MoveClip.

Answer (score 1):

в библиотеке, в свойствах мувика - укажите имя для класса (например MyMovieClip)
(галка Export For ActionScript)

в коде создаете новый экземпляр своего класса

```
var myMC:MyMovieClip = new MyMovieClip();
```

Comment: Не так поняли. Есть такой мувик, а там забиты уже все данные как координаты и тому подобные, надо сделать еще один, точно такой же, с такими координатами и всеми данными.

Comment: Если в коде класса мувика ничего подобного не прописано, то никак,
у стандартных наследников класса MovieClip ничего подобного нет.

Comment: Что разве нет никакой функций, которая копировала бы класс, а не делала на него ссылку, что теперь в ручную что ли прописывать, чтоб каждый параметр одного класса присваивался другому?

Comment: Ну, каждый параметр, это конечно крутовато, но необходимые свойства придется копировать (и, да, в AS3 нет возможности легко копировать рабочие экземпляры классов, никаких).

Comment: А вот в интернете нашел, кто-то говорит, что работает - у меня не хрена не работает `var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); bytes.writeObject (o); bytes.position = 0; bytes.readObject();`

Comment: В интернете еще публикуют способы полета к соседней звезде, и говорят, что работает и люди летают, я вот пробовал, и нихрена :)